# Abrir Jframe con click en Jtable (Netbeans)

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Estoy generando un Jtable que tiene varios datos, sin embargo necesito que al pinchar la primera celda de cada fila se abra un nuevo Jframe, he intentado con eventos, pero no logro generar que funcione especificamente ahi....
Por lo que necesito que seleccionar Numero de registro (sea 10 u 11 ) me abra un jframe y cargue dichos datos....

```
public void llamarMuestra() throws SQLException{
tblDatos.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new Render());
    JButton btn1 = new JButton("Modificar");
    btn1.setName("modificar");


    JButton btn2 = new JButton();

    btn2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Vista/Vista.Imagenes/eliminar.jpeg"));
    btn2.setName("eliminar");



        conectar cc = new conectar();
        Connection cn = cc.conexion();
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        JTable tabla = new JTable(modelo);
        String query = ("SELECT m.idMuestras, m.nregistro, c.nombrecliente, m.matriz, m.fechaingresolaboratorio, m.laboratorioejecutante, m.estado "
                + "FROM muestras m "
                //          + "INNER JOIN analisis a ON m.idMuestras = a.fk_idmuestras"
                + "INNER JOIN clientes c ON m.fk_idcliente = c.idClientes");
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet ResultSet = pst.executeQuery();
        modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"ID Muestras", "Numero Registro", "Cliente", "Matriz", "Analisis", "Ingreso Laboratorio", "Laboratorio Ejecutante", "Estado", "Modificar", "Eliminar"});
        System.out.println("INGRESO");
        try {
            while (ResultSet.next()) {
                int a = ResultSet.getInt("m.idMuestras");

                modelo.addRow(new Object[]{ResultSet.getInt("m.idMuestras"), ResultSet.getInt("m.nregistro"), ResultSet.getString("c.nombrecliente"),
                    ResultSet.getString("m.matriz"), Listaanalisis(a), ResultSet.getDate("m.fechaingresolaboratorio"),
                    ResultSet.getString("m.laboratorioejecutante"), ResultSet.getString("m.estado"), btn1, btn2});
                btn2.repaint();
            }
            tblDatos.setModel(modelo);
            tblDatos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
            tblDatos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
            tblDatos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(0);

            modelo.fireTableDataChanged();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(TableroMuestraLOQ_Recepcionista_Beta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            System.out.println("error con tabla");
        }
    }
```

[image: Jtable]

Comment: Como haces para modificar y que aparezca el codigo de manera correcta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar lo siguiente al evento onClick de la tabla, para que no se creen formularios repetidos debes chequear si es null, seria asi:

```
 NewJFrame newJFrame;
/**
 * Creates new form MainFrame
 */
public MainFrame() {
    initComponents();

    jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            //obtener la fila
            int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
            //obtener la columna
            int i = jTable1.getSelectedColumn();
            //si la columna es la 1era
            if (i == 0) {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
                String nro_registro = (String) model.getValueAt(row, i);
                if(newJFrame == null)
                    newJFrame = new NewJFrame(nro_registro);
                newJFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Me funciono pero me abre 1 mas por cada click, por ejemplo, la segunda vez que le hago click me abre 2 veces el mismo formulario, si hago click por tercerca vez, lo abre 3 veces y asi sucesivamente, como puedo limitarlo?